# aabb primitives of facets in cgal

Tags: cgal, primitive, aabb

I need to create ah aabb tree to make intersections between a volumetric mesh (c3t3) and many planes but I don’t know what primitive is better.

I try to use the facets of c3t3 but i don’t know how to implement